In bash/zsh, how to compare the metadata in two directories including . and excluding .. and the contents inside subdirectories?
Let's say that in a script, you have a directory $1 and its copy $2 and you'd like to compare the metadata (names, permissions, sizes, full modification dates, …) of the files and directories inside ignoring the contents of the subdirectories and ignoring the parents of $1 and $2. So far, my approach has been
#!/usr/bin/bash --
diff <(ls -al --full-time "$1" | tail -n +2) <(ls -al --full-time "$2" | tail -n +2)

The commands tail -n +2 skip the total count. However, there is a problem that the line for the parent .. is still there. And even if you manage to skip this line somehow (with sed?), then the alignment from this line remains.
So from the output of ls -la --full-time, say,
$ ls -la --full-time
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 username username  80 2024-06-25 02:41:10.159659992 +0200  .
drwxr-xr-x 26 username username 660 2024-06-25 02:41:00.343777548 +0200  ..
-rw-r--r--  1 username username   0 2024-06-25 02:41:10.159659992 +0200 'f  f'
-rw-r--r--  1 username username   0 2024-06-25 02:41:10.159659992 +0200 'f f'

we'd like to get, say,
drwxr-xr-x 2 username username 80 2024-06-25 02:41:10.159659992 +0200  .
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username  0 2024-06-25 02:41:10.159659992 +0200 'f  f'
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username  0 2024-06-25 02:41:10.159659992 +0200 'f f'

for the purpose of comparison with diff.
Note that no spaces are wasted and that the entry for this driectory '.' is still there!
How to do this in a script for bash (or zsh)? We cannot simply tell diff to ignore the actual number of consecutive spaces because the difference in the number of spaces in the filenames matters.

Presumably you're using GNU ls, in which you can omit only .. by using the --ignore/-I option:
% ls -la --full-time
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 muru muru 4096 2024-06-25 11:14:18.165432064 +0900 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 muru muru 4096 2024-06-25 11:13:51.405734089 +0900 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 muru muru    0 2024-06-25 11:14:18.165432064 +0900 ..foo
drwxr-xr-x 2 muru muru 4096 2024-06-25 11:13:51.405734089 +0900 bar
% ls -la --full-time -I ..
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 muru muru 4096 2024-06-25 11:14:18.165432064 +0900 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 muru muru    0 2024-06-25 11:14:18.165432064 +0900 ..foo
drwxr-xr-x 2 muru muru 4096 2024-06-25 11:13:51.405734089 +0900 bar

From the docs:

‘-I pattern’
‘--ignore=pattern’
In directories, ignore files whose names match the shell pattern (not
regular expression) pattern. As in the shell, an initial ‘.’ in a
file name does not match a wildcard at the start of pattern.
Sometimes it is useful to give this option several times. For example,
$ ls --ignore='.??*' --ignore='.[^.]' --ignore='#*'

The first option ignores names of length 3 or more that start with
‘.’, the second ignores all two-character names that start with
‘.’ except ‘..’, and the third ignores names that start with
‘#’.


-a lists all directory entries, that includes . and .. on systems where readdir() / getdents*() include them. Here, you could run ls twice, once for . with -d (ls -ld . will work even on systems where readdir() doesn't return it) and once with -A for the rest, excluding . and .. even on systems where readdir() returns them:
#! /usr/bin/bash --
list() {
  CDPATH= cd -P -- "$1" || return
  ls -ld --full-time -- .
  ls -lA --full-time | tail -n +2
}
exec diff -u <(list "$1") <(list "$2")

Note that while -a and -A are standard options, --full-time is GNU-specific.
With zsh, you could use its stat builtin to get all the information returned by lstat():
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat || exit
list() {
  CDPATH= cd -P -- "$1" && stat -nsLF%FT%T.%N%z -- . *(ND)
}
diff -u <(list "$1") <(list "$2")

zsh's glob expansions never include . nor .., even when you add the D qualifier like here to include hidden files.
